# program of single thread with timer in java

Tags: java, multithreading

any simple program for single thread with timer in java.

that thread will run with particular time.

i am new to this thread.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a ScheduledExecutorService, which can be obtained from one of the static factory methods on Executors.

Check out:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: hi
i want to call a one function, the name of function is addition(), this function take some time for execute. some time this is take over time for execute, so i would like to avoid the function execute more time, in that time i would like to end the function execution, the addition function executes in while loop, so i would like to set 10 seconds for each time calling the function. can u understand what is my problem?

Comment: Do you want to call addition repeatedly or just once?  

Also, can't you just test the current time in addition's loop?
  
  while (System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + (1000 * 10))
  {
     ...
  }

Comment: i called repeatedly,but the input of the addition function is different,so what will i do?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context of what you're trying to achieve? 

Also, are you able to modify the addition method?  I.e. could you put in the check I mentioned above?